# Maximizing a Double Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, optimization, calculus-of-variations

Consider a double integral

$$K= \int_{-a}^a \int_{-b}^b \frac{B}{r_1(y,z)r_2^2(y,z)} \sin(kr_1+kr_2) \,dy\,dz$$

where
$$r_1 =\sqrt{A^2+y^2+z^2}$$
$$r_2=\sqrt{B^2+(C-y)^2+z^2} $$

I want to maximize $K$ with respect to $ a, b, k, A, B$ and $C$. This involves differentiating K with respect to these variables and then solve the simultaneous equations.

Aside from this method, is there another way to maximize this double integral?

Comment: This is not a problem of calculus of variations, as K is not a functional in $C$. $K$ is a simple function of $C$. You should simply maximize it like a regular function derivating and equating to 0....

Comment: @DavidJaramillo Thank you. I wanted to find an alternative way to do it since the equations are messy. I'm very thankful for your help.